# A simple question of Littlewood-Paley decomposition.

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{f_k(x)\}_{k=0}^\infty$ be a Littlewood-Paley decompositon, that is, 
$$ f_k \in C_c^\infty $$ 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k (x) = 1,$$
$$ \text{supp} f_0 \subset \{ |x| \leq 2 \},$$
$$ \exists f \in C_c^\infty   \; \text{such that}\; \text{supp} f \subset \{ 2^{-1} \leq |x| \leq 2 \} \; \text{satisfying}\; f_k (x) = f(x/2^k).$$
Then I hope to show that for each $x$, there are at most 3 nonzero terms in the summation. Here $C_c^\infty$ means $C^\infty$ functions with compact support and $\text{supp}$ means the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support of $f_0$ is contained in $|x|\le 2$. The support of $f_k$ is contained in $2^{k-1}\le |x|\le 2^{k+1}$. On the base 2 logarithmic scale these ranges become
$$[-\infty, 1]\quad \text{ and  }\  [k-1,k+1], \ k=1,2,\dots \tag1$$
It should not be hard to see that every number $x$ is covered by at most three of the intervals in (1).